# SQL query to put people with the same last name and address into one row

Tags: sql

Suppose there was a SQL table like this:

```
Label Name | Last name | Address Line 1 | Address line 2
-----------+-----------+----------------+-------------------
John       | Smith     | 100 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Jane       | Smith     | 100 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Bill       | Doe       | 200 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Sam        | Rodgers   | 200 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Lisa       | Thompson  | 300 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Walter     | Thompson  | 300 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Chuck      | Thompson  | 300 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
```

What SQL query would produce a table like this?:

```
Label Name              | Last name | Address Line 1 | Address line 2
------------------------+-----------+----------------+-------------------
John and Jane           | Smith     | 100 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Bill                    | Doe       | 200 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Sam                     | Rodgers   | 200 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
Lisa, Walter, and Chuck | Thompson  | 300 Any St     | Anytown, WI, 50000
```

Comment: Well as @BrankoDimitrijevic has mentioned it is probably possible with usage of some database specific functions like say `group_concat` in mysql but we need to know again which DB you are using otherwise it will be a self joined table on the last name as far as I got it + this group_concat for the selected fields. That should do it.

Comment: @Solracnapod [There is no such thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms_sql_server#History) as "MS SQL Server **2010**". Which version are you actually using?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I am using: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.2500.0 and the database is hosted by SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do these kinds of things in the presentation layer, rather than in the DBMS.

But if you *really* want to do this at the DBMS level, and your DBMS is MS SQL Server (as your comment seems to indicate), you can do the following:

First, create a function that concatenates related `[Label Name]` values (using ',' and 'and' as separators):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CombineNames (
    @LastName nvarchar(max),
    @AddressLine1 nvarchar(max),
    @AddressLine2 nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @NameCount INT;

    SELECT @NameCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE
        [Last name] = @LastName
        AND [Address Line 1] = @AddressLine1
        AND [Address line 2] = @AddressLine2;

    DECLARE @List nvarchar(max);

    SELECT
        @List
            = COALESCE(@List, '')
            + (
                CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Label Name])
                WHEN 1 THEN ''
                WHEN @NameCount THEN ' and '
                ELSE ', '
                END
            )
            + CAST([Label Name] as nvarchar(max))
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE
        [Last name] = @LastName
        AND [Address Line 1] = @AddressLine1
        AND [Address line 2] = @AddressLine2
    ORDER BY
        [Label Name];

    RETURN (SELECT @List)

END
```

Then use the function like this:

```
SELECT
    dbo.CombineNames([Last name], [Address Line 1], [Address Line 2]),
    T.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT [Last name], [Address Line 1], [Address Line 2]
        FROM YOUR_TABLE
    ) T
```

Result:

```
(No column name)        Last name       Address Line 1      Address Line 2
----------------        ---------       --------------      --------------
Bill                    Doe             200 Any St          Anytown, WI, 50000
Sam                     Rodgers         200 Any St          Anytown, WI, 50000
Jane and John           Smith           100 Any St          Anytown, WI, 50000
Chuck, Lisa and Walter  Thompson        300 Any St          Anytown, WI, 50000
```

Answer (score 1):

None, that's not how sql works. You'll need to make an iteration either on SQL or another language to group your entries. The nearest thing you can get is:

```
John | Smith | 100 Any St | Anytown, WI, 50000
Jane | Smith | 100 Any St | Anytown, WI, 50000
```

And

```
Bill | Doe | 200 Any St | Anytown, WI, 50000
Sam | Rodgers | 200 Any St | Anytown, WI, 50000
```

And

```
Lisa | Thompson | 300 Any St | Anytown, WI, 50000
Walter | Thompson | 300 Any St | Anytown, WI, 50000
Chuck | Thompson | 300 Any St | Anytown, WI, 50000
```

You can get that with a simple GROUP BY statement

Note how you build an Statement:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table WHERE field2 = requirement;
          ^       ^      ^
          1       2      3
```

The number of fields you'll get is fixed, in this case, 3. And there's nothing you can do to make it sometimes 4 or sometimes 5. The only variable will be the number of records you get, but the format of their output is fixed and dictated by the query you make.